# How do I format Int32 numbers?

Tags: c#, .net, format, int, string.format

What is the best way to get formatted Int32 numbers?

Let say I have this `o` function:

```
string o(int x);
```

This is the value that `o` need to return according to `x`

```
x = 0    =>    o = 00
x = 1    =>    o = 01
x = 5    =>    o = 05
x = 10   =>    o = 10
x = 31   =>    o = 31
x = 106  =>    o = 106
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

when int x
use

```
 x.ToString("00");
 String.Format("{0:00}",x);
```

Comment: Wouldn't x.ToString( "D2" ) do this as well?

Answer (score 2):

```
string o(int x)
{
    return string.Format("{0:00}", x);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Can use [PadLeft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92h5dc07.aspx) to a total padding width of 2 with the character '0'.

```
string o(int x) {
    return x.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0');
}
```